# Any samples or any suggestions to achieve animations likeThirteen23 "blu" application?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

Thirteen23 have one twitter client application which is amazing. You can see the demo from this link
http://www.thirteen23.com/experiences/desktop/blu/. I want to do some animation like this for my startup/splash screen. Any Sample or suggestion how i can achive thesese kind of animation in WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The startup animation in that application is not done in WPF. It is a sequence of png images played back by WPF, prerendered in a external tool (Adobe After Effects). [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIF1O4PTwUo) is an example tutorial, how to generate particles.